# Merge multiple views with same functionality in one view

Tags: python, django, rest, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to define 4 GET endpoints (max,min,sum,avg) to access by REST. I did this but making 4 views, and I want to know if I can define the 4 methods in a single view.
I can't specify through the url which GET to hit. It's possible?

my urls.py set

```
urlpatterns =[
path('medidores/', MedidorView.as_view()),
path('mediciones/', MedicionView.as_view()),
path('medicion_max/<str:id>', MedicionMaxView.as_view()),
path('medicion_min/<str:id>', MedicionMinView.as_view()),
path('medicion_total/<str:id>', MedicionTotalView.as_view()),
path('medicion_prom/<str:id>', MedicionPromedioView.as_view())
]
```

my view.py set

```
class MedicionMaxView(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Max('consumo_kwh')))

class MedicionMinView(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Min('consumo_kwh')))

class MedicionTotalView(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Sum('consumo_kwh')))

class MedicionPromedioView(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Avg('consumo_kwh')))
```

Separate by name in urls but not have effect

**UPDATE:**

I put my urls like you

```
    urlpatterns =[
    path('medidores/', MedidorView.as_view()),
    path('mediciones/', MedicionView.as_view()),
    re_path(r'medicion/(?P<aggregation>(max|min|sum|avg))/<str:id>', MedicionView.as_view()),
    path('medicion_max/<str:id>', MedicionMaxView.as_view()),
    path('medicion_min/<str:id>', MedicionMinView.as_view()),
    path('medicion_total/<str:id>', MedicionTotalView.as_view()),
    path('medicion_prom/<str:id>', MedicionPromedioView.as_view())
]
```

But i cant match [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53qb4.png)

I don't know Stack Overflow rules but could share my git repository if needed. (although the code does not differ from what we were seeing here)
PS: I'm using google translate, sorry

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#views-extra-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can!

`as_view()` accepts parameters, so you can have one view like:

```
class MedicionView(View):
    aggregation=""
    def get(self, request, id):
        if self.aggregation == 'max':
            return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Max('consumo_kwh')))
        elif self.aggregation == 'min':
            return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Min('consumo_kwh')))
        elif self.aggregation == 'sum':
            return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Sum('consumo_kwh')))
        elif self.aggregation == 'avg':
            return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Avg('consumo_kwh')))
        else:
            # you can handle it
```

**Side note:** you can make this `get()` method more clean. For example, move the common calls one level up like `Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id)`

Now, can pass the needed aggregation way as parameter to `as_view()` with your URLs like:

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('medidores/', MedidorView.as_view()),
    path('mediciones/', MedicionView.as_view()),
    path('medicion_max/<str:id>', MedicionView.as_view(aggregation='max')),
    path('medicion_min/<str:id>', MedicionView.as_view(aggregation='min')),
    path('medicion_total/<str:id>', MedicionView.as_view(aggregation='sum')),
    path('medicion_prom/<str:id>', MedicionView.as_view(aggregation='avg'))
]
```

**Better way:**

You can even make it more clean by having one URL pattern for all of them by having the aggregation type as a URL parameter like:

```
class MedicionView(View):
    def get(self, request, aggregation, id):
        if aggregation == 'max':
            return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Max('consumo_kwh')))
        elif aggregation == 'min':
            return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Min('consumo_kwh')))
        elif aggregation == 'sum':
            return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Sum('consumo_kwh')))
        elif aggregation == 'avg':
            return JsonResponse(Medicion.objects.filter(medidor=id).aggregate(Avg('consumo_kwh')))
        else:
            # you can handle it
```

Now, you can have one URL pattern for them using regular expression:

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('medidores/', MedidorView.as_view()),
    path('mediciones/', MedicionView.as_view()),
    path(r'medicion/(?P<aggregation>(max|min|sum|avg))/<str:id>', MedicionView.as_view())
]
```

**Update:**

If you are following the second solution, don't forget to add the character `r` at the beginning of the URL patterns that follow a regex pattern as I did above.

Comment: More than solving it, you gave me a class on how to handle parameters. thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. please mark the answer as the correct one and mark it as useful or vote for it if so. Thanks.

Comment: Srry Yasser but I'm looking for a valid example that allows me to generate the endpoint to the url with regex and I can't find it. Could you tell me how to call the view? I am trying to use:
medicion/max/testid, I understand that it is wrong because it does not match with my view, it gives error 404 but why?

Comment: I tried to vote, but since I don't have enough reputation it won't let me

Comment: if you are following the second solution I have mentioned, so it you should reach the view using medicion/max/testid normally. max is a match for the regex to fetch the aggregation parameter and testid match the ID string parameter

Comment: @JuanManuelAmato, I have missed something in my answer that may cause about being unable to match with the regex. An update has been added. Sorry for that.

Comment: i can not solve :(, an update has been added. Thank you very much for the follow-up, it is appreciated